# facebook open graph stories with no app name

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've been trying to get the open graph story such that it doesn't show the app name using the following setting:

[image]

However every time I save this configuration, the "No App Name" is resetted back to 'on Shopious'. How is this even possible? Is this a facebook bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think there is a bug where you aren't getting an error when you save the config with "No App Name" selected.  An Open Graph action is always going to show the related app when posting to someone's Timeline.

Comment: What does the "No App Name" thing mean, then?

Comment: It's just a placeholder in the drop down list.  There should be no way to be able to save this form without choosing an app name as Open Graph requires it.